# SonicWall tz100 WAN to LAN "Received"

Tags: vpn, firewall, sonicwall

Background: I am interning at a company with an existing network setup. They are currently using a SonicWall tz100 for their hardware firewall. They are also using the Windows firewall. They want remote access to files on servers. My solution was to setup OpenVPN. I got this to work while inside the network (LAN to LAN). I used the packet monitoring and saw that the packets were being "FORWARDED".

The problem is that once I leave the network (in reality I just moved outside the firewall and connected straight to the modem), the packets are no longer "FORWARDING", instead they are "Received".

- I created the service for UDP on port 1194.
  [image: Service Object]
- I created address objects for the server's public IP
  [image: Address Object for public IP]
- I created address objects for the local IP
  [image: Address Object for local IP]
- I created the opening in the firewall for: 
  [image: Firewall Access Rule]
- I created the NAT:
  [image: Network NAT Policy]

I can post screenshots of the setup if you need.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To troubleshoot, I will investigate if the problem is on the FW (NAT or Access rule), an intermediate device, the server itself or de OpenVPN daemon. Your SonicWall config looks nice to me so I will check if packets are arriving at Server2012 server. Could you do a packet capture in your server? (tcpdump or wireshark will help)

Comment: Tip: I also suggest you modify access rule "Destination" = Server2012. Try to be the most granular possible ;).

Comment: I will install wireshark on the server on Monday I hope. I am not familiar with the tool, but I will give it a try. As for using "any" instead of "server2012" that was just me trying to be as broad as possible just to get it running.

Comment: Try changing your NAT Destination to be "WAN IP" so that when the Open VPN service hits your external IP it is translated to the server.  Also verify that the server's public IP is in the scope of your IP block configured on your WAN interface.

Comment: Alright, I changed Access Rule "Destination" = Server2012 again.
I also changed NAT Destination to "All WAN IP".
I did a Wireshark packet capture while inside the network, and could see the protocol type coming through as openvpn protocol. Once outside the network, I see no packets at all with openvpn protocol.

Comment: Couple of weeks now with no replies. Any ideas?